# In Bash, how can I rm files against a wildcard while supplying more than one exception?

Tags: bash, wildcards, rm

I have the following list of files:

```
main.acn
main.acr
main.alg
main.aux
main.glg
main.glo
main.gls
main.ist
main.lof
main.log
main.lot
main.nlo
main.out
main.pdf
main.tex
main.toc
```

I want to rm all of the `main.*` files except for **main.tex** and **main.pdf** file.

I tried `rm main.* !("main.tex","main.pdf")` but that did not work and removed all the `main.*`  without exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which shell? If it is bash do you have extglob set? The point about wildcards is that the shell expands them, so the `rm main.*` will give a list of all the files to `rm` to remove. You need to get your shell to give the correct list to rm.

Comment: I guess I'm lazy because I would just pipe `find` into `grep` and then `xargs rm`.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco note that that approach, which is actually considerably more typing, so I don't really see how you can call it "lazy", will fail on non-standard file names. Try it with a filename containing spaces or, even worse, a file name with a newline (`touch 'file name' file$'\n'newline`).

Comment: @terdon Laziness isn't always about typing less, sometimes it's about *thinking* less. If it takes you 10 minutes to write a 10-line shell script, and 30 minutes to learn a neat trick to do it in with 5 characters in sed, the shell script is the lazy option. Which is *better* depends on what you're trying to achieve: a successful result right now, or a learning opportunity for the future.

Comment: Fair enough. I just find `find [ find options ] -print0 | grep -z ... | xargs -I {} -0 $command` harder to do, both in terms of cognitive load and time it takes to write it correctly, but to each their own!

Comment: @terdon By correcting all the possible pitfalls, you've ended up with a straw man: the lazy approach referenced is likely just `find . | grep some-pattern | xargs rm` You were absolutely right that there are a bunch of times when that would go wrong; there are also a bunch of times when it would do exactly what's wanted, without needing to remember any option flags at all. And that's exactly what makes it lazy.

Comment: @terdon others have explained. You throw in an `echo` at the beginning of the `xargs` until it looks right. Anybody who puts newlines and spaces in their filenames need to learn their lessons.

Comment: @IMSoP oh wow, well anyone who does something like _that_ deserves what they will get! That is horrifyingly dangerous and fragile! It won't even handle file names with whitespace, let alone anything more exotic! 9 times out of 10, you can skip the find entirely and just use globs which are easier, clearer and more robust as shown in the answer here. But seriously, if you regularly run such things I can just about guarantee you will get in trouble. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Using_xargs_without_-0

Comment: This is the 21st century, @AaronD.Marasco. Real world filenames do contain spaces. (They don't usually contain newlines though. Fortunately.) If your code cannot handle spaces it's broken. Period

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`!("main.tex","main.pdf")` matches anything that isn't `main.tex,main.pdf`, so probably all files in the directory.

The key to note is that `!(...)` already acts like `*`, in that it itself matches anything that isn't one of the things inside. And the separator is `|`, not `,`.

So, `main.!(tex|pdf)` should work. Or `!(main.tex|main.pdf)` if you want to remove every file but those two, not just the ones with names that start with `main.`.

See:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html
- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob

Comment: I presume this is bash specific, this is not universal. If so, can we get the OP tagged bash?

Comment: `rm main.!(pdf|tex)` did the job perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesRisner This was for bash. I have tagged it for bash. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @JamesRisner, Bash (with `shopt -s extglob`), or ksh (should work by default), or zsh (with `setopt kshglob`). But yes, not standard POSIX shell.

Comment: @JamesRisner, that `!(x)` operator is from ksh from the early 80s. bash copied a subset of ksh extended operators and only  enables them with the `extglob` option.

Answer (score 9):

The less sophisticated route is to save the files you want to keep, delete everything (else), and put the saved files back again. It's also a POSIX compliant solution:

```
mkdir x                   # File or directory must not already exist
mv main.tex main.pdf x    # Save the files you want to keep
rm ./*                    # Ignore the error about not deleting 'x'
mv x/* .                  # Restore everything you saved. Notice the dot!
rmdir x                   # Tidy up
```

Here I've picked `x` as a file or directory that doesn't already exist. You *will* get an error from `rm` that it cannot delete `x`; that's good. Do not use `rm -rf`!

Notice that normally `rm ./*` will skip dot files.

Comment: As a one-off solution, this is absolutely the least sophisticated route to go and if I hadn't been given the perfect solution by @ikkachu, this is what I would have done. But the use of `rm main.!(pdf|tex)` is only mildly more sophisticated, while using 4 less commands, vastly more idiot-proof, scalable and teaches me something new.

Comment: The problem with `rm  main.!(pdf|tex)` is that it depends so much on which shell you're using and which options are set, so I wouldn't want this to become idiomatic.

Comment: You could name the directory `.x` instead of `x`, then `rm ./*` won't match `.x` in the first place, assuming nothing like `dotglob` is set.

Comment: @chepner indeed, but for the purposes of the illustration I felt that using `x` involved less "magic" for what was intended as a totally unsophisticated solution

Answer (score 7):

In Bash there is also the `GLOBIGNORE` variable, which can exclude/remove names from the list returned by a glob.  An example:

```
$ touch main.pdf main.tex one.pdf one.tex three.wow two.pdf two.tex
$ echo *
main.pdf main.tex one.pdf one.tex three.wow two.pdf two.tex
$ GLOBIGNORE='main.tex:main.pdf'
$ echo *
one.pdf one.tex three.wow two.pdf two.tex
```

`GLOBIGNORE` can be a list of expressions (colon-separated) that describe the names to ignore, as the above example shows.  Your question was about excluding a pair of simple filenames, but you can use glob expressions too:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE='one.*:two.*'
$ echo *
main.pdf main.tex three.wow
```

The list of names matching the glob (`*` in these examples) is evaluated against the expressions in `GLOBIGNORE`. The names that match any of the expressions are removed from the list.  It's a useful feature.

In many cases, it's also useful to use `export`, as in `export GLOBIGNORE='main.tex:main.pdf'`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into a situation like this, I do it with a pipe:

ls -1 main.* | egrep -v '\.pdf|\.tex' | xargs rm

Comment: That will break horribly for file names containing spaces Or file names matching names in directories matching the glob `main.*`.

Comment: Personally, I avoid spaces in file names, but if there were, you could insert a pipe with a sed to add in backslashes.  Other go-arounds if there happens to be a directory named e.g. "main.directory"  , for example  "ls -1" => "ls -1dF | egrep -v '\/ *$' | sed -e's/\\* *$//g' -e's/ /\\ /g' . . .  Haven't tested this but usually I play around until it works and leave out the "xargs rm" while I am playing.

Comment: Ugly, for sure, but quick. (I MEANT TO WRITE:  ls -1  main.*  ==> ls -1dF main.*)