# Matching negative patterns with bash extglob

Tags: bash, wildcards

Consider I have a set of seven files:

```
item1_data
item2_data_more
item3_data
item4_data
item5_data_more
other6_data
other7_data_more
```

and I want to match the three of them that begin with `item` but do not end with `more`. Given that this is an example scenario you have to accept that it is not sufficient to match with the positive matching pattern `item*data?` (or any trivial variant).

I'm using `bash` with `extglob` enabled. For simple cases the description in the man page is sufficient ("***`!(pattern‐list)`** Matches anything except one of the given patterns*"). However, here I need to achieve a match on `item` but a negative match for `data`. I finally landed on one that works but what I do not understand is why it works but others fail.

```
shopt -s extglob                                                # Enable extended globbing
touch {item{1,3,4},other6}_data {item{2,5},other7}_data_more    # Example data set

ls !(*more)                                                     # Non-"item" files too
item1_data  item3_data  item4_data  other6_data

ls item*!(more)                                                 # All "item" files
item1_data  item2_data_more  item3_data  item4_data  item5_data_more

ls item!(*more)                                                 # Works as required
item1_data  item3_data  item4_data
```

Why does the second of these fail and the third succeed? I'm thinking that the wildcard should be valid in either position - but clearly isn't. Can someone enlighten me, please.

Comment: If you want to prevent some items from appearing in a list generated by a glob (in bash), have a look in the man page for the `GLOBIGNORE` variable.  A fuller description can be found in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722852/531636).

Comment: @SottoVoce thank you for the link reference. The `GLOBIGNORE` isn't relevant to me here, but the other answer on that link was just what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I needed is found in one of [the other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722842/100397) to the question [In Bash, how can I rm files against a wildcard while supplying more than one exception](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/722840/100397) referenced through [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762766/matching-negative-patterns-with-bash-extglob#comment1455224_762766) to my question.

The relevant phrase for me is this,

> **The key to note is that `!(…)` already acts like `*`**, in that it itself matches anything that isn't one of the things inside.

I wasn't thinking of it as being equivalent to `*`, and that was the blocker to my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the second expression fails because `item*` matches the entire filename for each of these files, and the empty string at the end trivially matches `!(more)`.

Comment: That's the thing. Also something like `foo!(bar)` matches `foo` and `foodoo` (but of course not `foobar`), etc.